# Specify table name for ejb 2.1 many to many relationship

Tags: jboss, ejb, myeclipse, ejb-2.x, xdoclet

I have an ejb 2.1 m:n relationship.
The table is being created automatically.
The thing is I want to specify the table name that is going to be created by this relationship.

**The question:**
Does a many to many relationship have an attribute to specify which table name I want to be created instead of the default table name (which is a concatenation of the tables involved in the relationship)? Or there is another way to achieve that?

**Details**
I am using:

- XDoclet
- Myeclipse
- EJB 2.1
- jboss-4.2.3.GA

I am pretty sure the question is specific enough, but in any case below is the relationship code

```
/**
 * @ejb.interface-method view-type="both"
 * @ejb.relation
 *     name="empresas-campanhas"
 *     role-name="campanha de empresas"
 *     target-role-name="empresas tem campanhas"
 *     target-ejb="Empresa"
 *     target-multiple="yes"
 * @ejb.value-object
 *     compose="<package>.EmpresaValue"
 *     compose-name="EmpresaValue"
 *     members="<package>.EmpresaLocal"
 *     members-name="EmpresaLocal"
 *     relation="external"
 * @jboss.relation
 *     fk-column="id_empresa"
 *     fk-constraint="true"
 *     related-pk-field="idEmpresa"
 * @jboss.target-relation
 *     fk-column="ID_CampanhaFidelidade"
 *     fk-constraint="true"
 *     related-pk-field="idCampanhaFidelidade"
 */
public abstract Collection getEmpresas();

/**
 * @ejb.interface-method view-type="both"
 */
public abstract void setEmpresas( Collection empresas );
```

It is being created the table:

`campanhafidelidade_empresas_empresa_campanhafidelidade_empresas`

But I want to specify:

`syo_campanhafidelidade_empresas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the following annotation in the `getEmpresas()` method:

```
@jboss.relation-table table-name="SYO_CampanhaFidelidade_Empresas"
```